# How to find the character "\" in a string?

Tags: c++, string

I am trying to manipulate a string by finding the \ character in the string Find\inHere. However, I can't put that as an input in `test.find('\', 0)`. It won't work and gives me the error "missing terminating character." Is there a way to fix `test.find('\', 0)`?

```
string test = "Find\inHere";

int x = test.find('\', 0);   // error on this line
cout << x;   // x should equal 4
```

Comment: have you tried test.find('\\', 0);?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\` is a character used to introduce special characters, for example `\n` newline, `\xDB` shows the ASCII character with hexadecimal number DB etc.

So, in order to search this special character, you have to escape it by adding another `\`, use:

```
test.find("\\",0);
```

EDIT : Also, in your first string, it is not written in it "Find\inHere" but "Find" and an error because `\inHere` isn't a special instruction. So, same way to avoid it, write "Find\\inHere".

Comment: Thank you! I am not sure what you mean by to avoid it, write "Find\inhere". The only difference is the capital H "Find\inHere".

Comment: Indeed sorry, it's edited now. But the difference is the double \\ to escape the \ character, so that it does not interpret what is next to '\' as an instruction.